# ARMSIM Display Hex of each character in a word

Tags: arrays, arm, hex

Using ARMSIM, a user enters a word and I need to display the hex value of character to the screen. I can get the word, the length, and I know how to implement a loop.

Problem--I don't know how to move character-to-character or convert from ASCII to hex.

You assistance is appreciated.

Comment: define in binary what you mean by hex value, character.  When you say they enter a word do you mean "hello".  do you mean for example the user enters ABC and the output is 41 42 43 or something like that?

Comment: If a person enters "Agreement" (without the quotes), decimal for A is 65 with hex being 41. I don't need to display the decimal values for each, but I do need the hex for each separated by a space (41 67 72 65 65 6D 65 6E 74).

Comment: so in binary there is a byte somewhere in memory with 0b01000001 which is also 0x41 which is also 65.  If you look at your ascii chart you want to turn that 0x41 in memory into a 0x34 and a 0x31  so you take 0100 and if less than or equal to 9 then add 0x30 take the lower four bits if less than or equal to 9 then add 0x30,  there are your two output bytes.  will let you figure out what to do if the nibble is greater than 9

Comment: then how you display that ascii byte for "4" and "1" to the screen is a whole other deal which is generally system/operating system dependent so you have to look at ARMSIM specifically as to how to do that.

Comment: Okay, but right now I have the word "Agreement" in, say, r7. How do I get to the A g r ....?

Comment: r7 can only hold 32 bits, that is four bytes so it is not possible for r7 to hold the whole word.  It might be an address to the string that contains the word it might be the address to the letter "A" and then you work through the string, that depends on how you are getting the string/word in the first place.  use ldrb to load a byte from memory using an address. depending on which flavor of instruction set (arm, thumb, thumb2 extensions to thumb) you can auto increment the address in one instruction ldrb r1,[r7],#1 and r1 now contains "A" assuming r7 is a pointer to a string, then after r7

Comment: points to "g".  keep reusing that instruction until you hit the end of the string which is a different discussion, how did you get this string what is the definition is r7 a pointer to a string or what. is it pascal style with a length and then the string or C style that is zero terminated or unicode two bytes (or more?) per character, etc...